# How can I avoid re-fetching disabled css file

Tags: html, css, vue.js, darkmode

I am trying to implement dark theme on my website and I currently do it by including 2 style sheets:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/flatly.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/darkly.css">
```

and then adding/removing the "disabled" attribute to the darkly css link to disable/enable dark theme.

This does work, but every time I click the enable button a new network request is made to download the darkly.css file, which causes a small lag in rerendering.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Javascript to add and remove the `disabled` attribute. If so can you copy and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you are adding and removing the  disabled property. Using pure JS, it's not to be re-fetching.

There's [this little](https://gist.github.com/wandersonpjbkn/568c3a252dea16166aa85ccdf00ab36b) gist running this process.